# The use of CommandButton Shape into a form locks the navigation bar

Tags: locking, shapes, commandbutton

If I use text boxes in a form, whose display parameters (text, height, width, position, background color, ...) are contained in a table, everything goes smoothly; if instead of text boxes I use command buttons with different shapes (depending precisely on the parameters contained in the same table), the latter situation blocks the selection of items in the navigation menu.
Any ideas on what causes the menu to freeze and what to do to avoid it?
Thank you!

First of all, it should be written that, in my case, to change the shape of the button via VBA, I initially had to assign one that was not the classic "squared" one, so I assigned to any button the "circular" shape.